# I'm having trouble writing static methods

Tags: java

I'm not very experienced in making static methods...I wanted some practice and I'm having some problems. I'm trying to make a program where you input a number and it prints out all the squares less than b. For example, if you put in 100, it returns 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81.
I'm getting errors, though.

- Illegal modifier for parameter getSquares; only final is permitted. This is on the line public static double getSquares(double b)

-The method getSquares(int) is undefined for the type Squares when I try to do Squares.getSquares(100);...I'm guessing this is because of my first problem. Please help me, I know static methods are important but I don't know how to make them.

```
package Testers;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Squares 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Squares.getSquares(100);

        public static double getSquares(double b)
        {
            double sqrtNum=Math.sqrt(b);
            int i=0;
            while(i<sqrtNum)
            {
                sqrtNum=Math.pow(i,2);
                System.out.print(sqrtNum+" ");
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're declaring a method inside of a method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't declare a method inside a method - format your code and it is clearer to see. Example:

```
package Testers;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Squares {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Squares.getSquares(100);   
    }

    public static double getSquares(double b) {
        double sqrtNum = Math.sqrt(b);
        int i = 0;
        while(i < sqrtNum) {
            sqrtNum = Math.pow(i, 2);
            System.out.print(sqrtNum + " ");
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, there is no returned value in `getSquares()` - it looks like you intended to make it `void`.
Finally, this `while` loop:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < sqrtNum) {
    // code
    i++;
}
```

can be simplified to this `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sqrtNum; i++) {
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your static method should not be in main() if you want it to be a method of the Squares class.  it should be in Squares and not in main, like:

```
public class Squares
{
     public static void main(..) {...}
     public static double getSquares(...) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring your method in another method, which doesn't work.  Put it outside and it should be good.

```
package Testers;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Squares 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Squares.getSquares(100);


    }

    public static double getSquares(double b)
    {
        double sqrtNum=Math.sqrt(b);
        int i=0;
        while(i<sqrtNum)
        {
            sqrtNum=Math.pow(i,2);
            System.out.print(sqrtNum+" ");
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @bcsb1001 I've corrected the formatting; there was some issues with tabs and I needed to open notepad.

Answer (score 1):

In your getSquares method you need a return statement.